# Allocation of string, recursive function of two strings in one

Tags: c, string, recursion

I wrote a recursive function that gets 3 strings, out of which two were sorted in alphabetic order and the third one was allocated to put first two strings inside the third. The alphabetic order should stay; for example:

```
s1="abbcde";
s2="bckj";
```

So,

```
s3="abbbccdekj";
```

This is the allocation of the third string in `main()`:

```
char *s3 = (char*)malloc(len*sizeof(char));
SS1together(s1,s2,s3);//send to recursive function 3 strings
```

and this is the function:

```
   void SS1together(char *s1, char*s2, char*s3)
{
if (s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL)
{
    if (s1 == NULL)
    {
        s3[0] = s2[0];
        SS1together(s1, s2 + 1, s3 + 1);

    }
    else
    {
        s3[0] = s1[0];
        SS1together(s1 + 1, s2, s3 + 1);
    }
}
if (s1 != NULL && s2 != NULL)
{
    if (s1[0] <= s2[0])
    {
        s3[0] = s1[0];
        SS1together(s1 + 1, s2, s3 + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        s3[0] = s2[0];
        SS1together(s1 , s2 + 1, s3 + 1);
    }
}
}
```

It shows that the problem is with memory, but I can't find it.

My allocation of string 3, in main function, there is one more function that works perfectly, so I put the main for the full picture:

```
  void main()
{
char *s1[N], *s2[N], *s3[N];//N=30 ,it is define in the top
int ans, len;

printf("Please enter your string  s1 and then string s2\n");
gets(s1);
gets(s2);
len = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);

if ((CheckS(s1) == 0) || (CheckS(s2) == 0))
    printf("Not sorted\n");
else
{
    char *s3 = (char*)malloc(len*sizeof(char));
    SS1together(s1,s2,s3);
    puts(s3);
    free(s3);
}
_getch();
}
```

Comment: You don't show how `len` is calculated (it needs to be `strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1`), and you don't show how the output string is null terminated (though it might happen automatically — I've got some chasing to do before claiming it doesn't; but I'm worried about the recursion in the first `if` clause if `s2[0] == '\0'` at the same time `s1[0] == '\0'`).

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to do [something like this](http://pastebin.com/itdn6GYU), which is likely more brief than you may first think). And your posted code is missing a `+1` on the allocation of `s3` to account for the ensuing terminator.

Comment: this kind of line: 's3[0] = s2[0];' does NOT copy a string, all it copies is the first byte of the string.  What is actually needed is: 'strcpy( s3, s2);'  and the s3 needs to be s3 = malloc( strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);  note: sizeof(char) is always 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're moderately close, but haven't fully considered the terminating conditions.  It is also a whole heap easier to merge sorted data iteratively than it is recursively.

You don't show how len is calculated (it needs to be `strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1`), but your code can run into problems even if that's correct.  For example, consider the simplest case, two empty strings.  The first `if` executes, but the recursion goes to use `s2 + 1` which is beyond the end of the string, and leads to disaster.  Fixing that requires, I think, code similar to this:

```
void SS1together(char *s1, char *s2, char *s3)
{
    if (s1 == NULL || s1[0] == '\0')
    {
        s3[0] = s2[0];
        if (s2[0] != '\0')
            SS1together(s1, s2 + 1, s3 + 1);
    }
    else if (s2 == NULL|| s2[0]=='\0')
    {
        s3[0] = s1[0];
        if (s1[0] != '\0')
            SS1together(s1 + 1, s2, s3 + 1);
    }
    else if (s1[0] <= s2[0])
    {
        s3[0] = s1[0];
        SS1together(s1 + 1, s2, s3 + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        s3[0] = s2[0];
        SS1together(s1, s2 + 1, s3 + 1);
    }
}
```

<sup>*Warning: untested code.*</sup>

Iterative alternative

```
void SS1together(char *s1, char *s2, char *s3)
{
    if (s1 == NULL)
        s1 = "";
    if (s2 == NULL)
        s2 = "";
    while (*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0')
    {
        if (s1[0] <= s2[0])
            *s3++ = *s1++;
        else
            *s3++ = *s2++;
    }
    while (s1[0] != '\0')
        *s3++ = *s1++;
    while (s2[0] != '\0')
        *s3++ = *s2++;
    *s3 = '\0';
}
```

<sup>*Warning: also untested code.*</sup>

Comment: I forgot len=strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that when `s1` is `NULL` (the first `if`), `s2` is not `NULL` and increments `s2` and does recursive call.

But when `s2` string is smaller than `s1`, `s2` will reach to the end first so passing `s2+1` in recursive call would result in accessing out of bound memory. This technically results in undefined behavior and practically most likely memory access violation causing crash.

You should do more stringent NULL checks before incrementing the pointers - `s1`, `s2` and `s3`.

Comment: I fixed it to: if (s1 == NULL || s1[0] == '\0' || s2 == NULL || s2[0] == '\0') this is the first if and then inside two more if, one for s1==NULL and the other for s2==NULL but there is still problem/

Comment: @t_box24: update your question without invalidating this answer (so add the modified code rather than replacing the original).  You can control the format in the question; you can't format in comments meaningfully.

Comment: @t_box24, the tests should also be for `*s1==NULL` or `*s2== NULL`.